# Java while(true) loop runs once

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops, server

I am writing a Server-Multiclient communication application, and I need to make a `Thread` that loops and accepts clients. My current code is:

```
Thread acceptor = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            System.out.println("looking for clients");
            try{
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientList.add(new ConnectionToClient(s));
                }
                catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
    }
};
acceptor.setDaemon(true);
acceptor.start();
```

However, when I run my application, the text `looking for clients` only appears one time, and no clients can connect.

I don't understand why my `while(true)` loop isn't actually looping, and only running once.

EDIT:

The `ConnectionToClient` constructor is:

```
ConnectionToClient(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    Thread read = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                try {
                    Object obj = in.readObject();
                    messages.put(obj);
                } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    read.start();
 }
```

Comment: What do you think `acceptor.setDaemon(true);` does? How many clients are actually trying to connect?

Comment: I am trying to make it support as many clients as I want, but I've been testing it with 1 - 3 clients and that never works.

Comment: As per the javadocs for `accept` - `The method blocks until a connection is made.`

Comment: Also `The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I understand that, but when the client is open, it errors when the server shuts down, and never connects while it is alive.

Comment: Show the code of the constructor `ConnectionToClient(Socket s)`. If the problem is not (just) the daemon thread, then it must that constructor that is not returning. Are you trying to read from the socket in the constructor?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I edited it in. Is that the problem?

Comment: @C.Cole Yes, that's likely the problem. The constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads the header - the first few bytes of the stream. So it will block until the client sends those bytes, and in that period you are not accepting new connections. You should move the construction of the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream to the Thread `read` as well.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt wow! thanks so much. that fixed it. I would have never been able to figure that out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @ErwinBolwidt.

The problems were:

1) The `.setDaemon(true)` was causing problems.

2) Creating the `ObjectInputStream` before the client was connected was reading the header that needed to be sent to the server, and blocking the client from sending it to the server. Moving that to the read thread allowed the client to actually connect to the server.

Thanks again @ErwinBolwidt.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `acceptor.setDaemon(true);`.

[Its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-) explains:

> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread 
>   or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only 
>   threads running are all daemon threads.

So you're marking your only running thread as a daemon thread (since your main thread ends when the `main` method ends). You're lucky that you got one iteration of the loop, since your VM almost immediately exits as there are no more non-daemon threads.

Solution: remove the line that reads `acceptor.setDaemon(true);`

---

Your updated post shows the other problem, the constructor `ConnectionToClient(Socket socket)` inadvertently tries to read from the `Socket`, which blocks the acceptor thread until the client sends data.

The problem is the constructor of `ObjectInputStream` tries to read the header of the object stream.

Therefor, you should move the construction of the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` into the `read` Thread, so that this doesn't block the `acceptor` Thread.

Comment: Just removed all traces of `acceptor.setDaemon(true);` and it still runs once.

Comment: @C.Cole Maybe you haven't rebuilt the class files yet?

Comment: Also, my VM does not exit. It just waits with the `looking for clients` text.

Comment: I think your code should say `waiting for client` and that is what it is doing, it is waiting for a client to connect

Comment: I made the client application print if it was connected, and it always prints `true`, but the server doesn't ever try to look for more clients, and the client never receives any data.